# How to find $r$ in an equation like this: $r^3= xr+y$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

Can anyone give me an an idea how to solve this and find $r$, where $r^3= xr+y$ and $x$ and $y$ are known numbers?

Comment: By using the Tschirnhausen transformation you can bring any third degree equation $r^3 + a r^2 + b r + c = 0$ into the form $r^3 = x r + y$. So you are actually asking how to solve the third degree equation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are more elegant methods, but one simple approach is to turn it into a polynomial in $r$ as such:

$$r^3 -xr - y = 0$$

and then apply the cubic formula (it's not so bad since there is no $r^2$ term) to obtain

$$r = 
\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 + \left(-\frac{x}{3}\right)^3}} + 
\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 + \left(-\frac{x}{3}\right)^3}}$$

Comment: Also see [Reduction to a depressed cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic) and the solution methods below that point in the Wikipedia article on the cubic function.